# Find the errors in the BankMenu method

Tags: java

The method bankTellerMenu() is intended to show a bank teller menu and repeatedly obtain the user’s selection and execute that selection. The menu is only redisplayed if an invalid choice is made by the user. There are syntax and logical errors in the method. If these errors were corrected then the actual output would match that displayed below.
Correct the code and test it by producing the output below. I have underlined user responses to make them stand out.

------------------------- Expected output --------------------------

FIT Bank

1. Deposit
2. Withdraw
3. Client Menu
4. Account Menu
5. Exit

Select an option (1-5): **7**

FIT Bank

1. Deposit
2. Withdraw
3. Client Menu
4. Account Menu
5. Exit

Option must be only 1-5

Select an option (1-5): **2**

*** Invoke withdraw()

Select another option (1-5): **5**

------------------------- Expected output --------------------------

***Now the problem starts now, i have tried out coding the method, but it doesn't seem to be able to invoke withdraw() or any other choices when i input a value that is between 1 and 5. Can someone help please?***

```
import java.util.*;

public class FITBank
{
    //There are no errors in the main method.
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Just run bank teller menu.
        bankTellerMenu();
    }


public static void bankTellerMenu()
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = 1;                
    String message = null;

    do{
            System.out.println("\n\tFIT Bank");
            System.out.println("1. Deposit");
            System.out.println("2. Withdraw");
            System.out.println("3. Client Menu");
            System.out.println("4. Account Menu");
            System.out.println("5. Exit");
            if(message!=null){
            System.out.println("\t"+message);
            }
            System.out.print("Select an option (1-5): ");
            option = reader.nextInt();

        if(option < 1 || option > 5){
                message = new String("Option must be only 1-5");
                option=1;
            }

        }while(option <1 && option > 5);



    if(option == 1) {

        System.out.println("***\tInvoke deposit()");

        }

            if(option == 2){
                System.out.println("***\tInvoke withdraw()");

            }

                if(option == 3)
                {   System.out.println("***\tInvoke clientMenu()");

            }


                if(option==4){
                    System.out.println("***\tInvoke accountMenu()");

                }


    }
}
```

Comment: Is this condition correct? while(option >=1 && option < 5); Do you want to keep on prompting if option is between 1 & 5?

Comment: its questions for practice to improving my programming skills @thinksteep oh! i understand now that you explained to me, its seems really hard to think in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost: are you familiar with [the switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)? If you're not, then I think this would be a perfect time to learn about it.

> Now the problem starts now, i have tried out coding the method, but it doesn't seem to be able to invoke withdraw() or any other choices when i input a value that is between 1 and 5.

Without doing your homework: if you want to invoke the `withdraw` method, you must have a `withdraw` method to invoke. So where is your `withdraw` method? Or are you just supposed to print that you're calling the `withdraw` method without actually calling it?

Comment: I didnt need the methods for invoking, just have to say that it is done, which i did but saying invoke withdraw etc. also, thanks for the switch statement link, i shall look into it more

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your loop to early. Move all the `if(option == ...)` statements right before
`}while(option >=1 && option < 5);`. Otherwise this won't work as expected.

Also I would recommend using a `switch` statement instead of all those `if` statements.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, it now works, but the problem is that when i input a value that can start a invoke method, it produces the  output:
 FIT Bank
1. Deposit
2. Withdraw
3. Client Menu
4. Account Menu
5. Exit
Select an option (1-5): 3
*** Invoke clientMenu()
Select another option (1-5): <-----this last part i do not need, do you have any suggestions how to remove this part when i choose options 1-4?